there is almost no peer to connect , how to solve it? thanks a bunch
./geth --holesky    --http --http.api=eth,net,web3,txpool  --http.corsdomain '*' --port 30303 --txpool.globalslots=250000 --txpool.globalqueue=50000 console
but the result is :
WARN [09-06|18:15:22.384] Engine API enabled                       protocol=eth
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.385] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.14.9-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.23.0
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.408] New local node record                    seq=1,725,617,618,234 id=68ad93a5b1ed3029 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.418] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://00da0bd32d3d68564b083ad6af3353ef644aab9bafb022de234c3f29d38036fc5a4c3668c195ce43fc4cffe5966b5afcc059bd7b6cdcf7317a4f7725c193b1cf@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.420] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/gilsun91/.ethereum/holesky/geth.ipc
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.420] Loaded JWT secret file                   path=/home/gilsun91/.ethereum/holesky/geth/jwtsecret crc32=0xb87c9348
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.420] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 auth=false prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.420] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [09-06|18:15:22.420] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true  prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.14.9-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.23.0
at block: 0 (Thu Sep 28 2023 19:55:00 GMT+0800 (CST))
 datadir: /home/gilsun91/.ethereum/holesky
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 engine:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> INFO [09-06|18:15:32.567] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=171 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:15:42.988] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=168 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:15:53.068] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=141 static=0
WARN [09-06|18:15:57.386] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
INFO [09-06|18:16:03.075] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=131 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:16:13.193] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=147 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:16:23.307] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=171 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:16:33.515] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=175 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:16:43.537] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=132 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:16:53.550] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=166 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:17:03.695] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=126 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:17:14.089] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=134 static=0
INFO [09-06|18:17:24.112] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=127 static=0

so you can see that there is almost no peer, how to solve it? thanks a bunch .

Usually lack of peer-to-peer discoverability is because your server does not have a public IP address, or cannot pierce firewall/NAT.

thanks a bunch!
